# Remove 2 fragment inside linearlayout

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming. I have tried to make 2 fragment show in leave_content_container

```
      Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.leave_content_container);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(new ExpandableDataProviderFragmentLeave(), FRAGMENT_TAG_EXPANDABLE_DATA_PROVIDER_LEAVE)
            .commit();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.leave_content_container, new EmployeeLeaveAddExpandableFragment(), FRAGMENT_LIST_VIEW)
            .commit();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(new ExpandableDataProviderFragmentLeave1(), FRAGMENT_TAG_EXPANDABLE_DATA_PROVIDER_LEAVE_1)
            .commit();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.leave_content_container, new EmployeeLeaveAddExpandableFragment1(), FRAGMENT_LIST_VIEW)
            .commit();
```

When I am done I want to remove all this fragment and replace it with new another fragment

```
  Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.leave_content_container);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(new ExpandableDraggableSwipeableDataProviderFragmentLeave(), FRAGMENT_TAG_DATA_PROVIDER).commit();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.leave_content_container, new ExpandableDraggableSwipeableFragmentLeave(), FRAGMENT_LIST_VIEW)
                    .commit();
```

The problem is when I remove two of the older fragment only one is removed. How do I remove all of the fragment inside leave_content_container? Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the fragment you want by its tag:

```
    Fragment frag1 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG_1);
    Fragment frag2 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG_2);

    //P.S: multiple operations can be done in the same transaction
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction
            .remove(frag1)
            .remove(frag2)
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily remove all of fragments by doing this :

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.leave_content_container)).commit();
```

It will remove the fragments that is loded in your container.

Comment: It's not working. This code just removes lastest yield fragment the other fragment still remains.